# How to debug u-boot issue?

Tags: boot, boot-loader, u-boot, yocto, beagleboneblack

I am working on putting a custom system together on the Beaglebone Black.  Things work most of the time, but every once in a while, the system will fail to boot when powered on.  This never happens when a serial debug cable is connected (so that I'm able to watch the u-boot and kernel messages.)

However, what I've found is that, on the rare times that it fails, if I then connect a serial cable, I find that I'm sitting at a u-boot prompt.  If I manually set up u-boot to load the kernel and all from there, I can boot just find (it can read the eMMC and such).

My first thought was that there was some sort of noise on the serial line that was causing u-boot to break (defaults to break on space in 2 seconds, I believe).  However, I recompiled u-boot to use a 0-second delay (doesn't wait for spacebar), but that didn't fix the problem.

How can I figure out why u-boot is halting without connecting a serial cable during the boot (because that makes the problem go away; Heisenbug)?  Is there any sort of logging enabled I can access?

Comment: Noticed I was wrong.  It's any key to interrupt u-boot, and even though the delay is 0, holding down a key will still cause it to break, so maybe something like that is still my problem?  How can I be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a board one time where the uart RX pin was tied to ground. So u-boot always saw a key press.

Don't know what version you are using...

In

`/common/autoboot.c`

function

`static int abortboot_normal(int bootdelay)`

just before the return add the line

`abort = 0;`

This will return no key pressed.

Comment: Glad it helped. Your welcome